Where to put equation number when the range is on the separate line?
I always put numbers for multi-line equations as follows (e.g., using equation and gathered):

My co-author wants to do (e.g., using gather and nonumber).

Is there a commonly accepted convention for such instances?

This is really off-topic. How to do it would be on-topic; whether to do it not. Could you ask on another site specific to your discipline?

@cfr I wouldn't call it off-topic. The question is about typing LaTeX documents.

@Michael_1812 By that logic, keyboards are on-topic, as are questions about the conventions used in recipe books, nursery timetables and guides for ramblers. Typographic conventions etc. are off-topic. How to realise them is on-topic. This isn't my personal view. I'm just reporting the scope of the site.

@Michael_1812 See e.g. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/typesetting-and-typography-related-questions, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/679/what-should-the-policy-be-on-typography-design-questions, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6647/are-is-this-good-typography-questions-on-topic, or, generally, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=typography. This one would be more plausibly on-topic imho if it included the code used to implement each option rather than applying as much to Word as TeX.

It would have been helpful if you had provided some information about the relative importance of the two equations in question. Are they roughly equally important, and are you likely to be referring to both equations in a cross-reference to this group of equations? If so, use your positioning approach. Conversely, is the first equation more important (in whatever sense of the term "important" that may be applicable here) than the second, and can a cross-reference to the group of equations only meaningfully be interpreted as referring to the first equation? If so, use your colleague's approach.

To me, referring between two lines as in your top image looks weird. It gets better if you add a brace to the right, if you want to be able to refer to the two equations as one. Here are a few alternatives. In case you only want to refer to one of the two equations you can in the second and third example just remove one of the numbers. I think this question will be closed as off topic, though.

There is no right or wrong for this case. What you can do, in order to please yourself as well as your coauthor, is to define a specific environment. You can eventually fight with your coauthor and the winner will decide what option to use.
Of course, the formula doesn't make sense, but I'll ignore the fact.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% for mock text

\newenvironment{equationcondition}
 {\begin{equation}\begin{gathered}[t]}
 {\end{gathered}\end{equation}\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\kant[10][1-2]
\begin{equationcondition}
H=\sum_{J\in S}H_{J} \\
J=\{j_{1},\dots,j_{k}\}\in S,\quad j_{i}\in\Lambda
\end{equationcondition}
\kant[20][1-2]

\end{document}


If you just remove [t] from the definition, you get

Much better, if the main formula is not too long, would be using a single line.


I, personally, always place equation numbers the way you do, and I cannot recall a case when a technical editor of journal changed it.
As a reader, I also would prefer this manner of numbering, and my guess is that most readers will share my opinion.
